# What is the difference between cloneDeep(a) and extend({}, a) in lodash?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, lodash, extend

For a long time I was thinking that

```
_.extend({}, obj) is the same as _.cloneDeep(obj)
```

in lodash.

But I found out that object, created with `extend` function has the same `__proto__` hash, unlike object, created with `cloneDeep` function.

---

Please, explain what is the difference between Lodash's `cloneDeep` and `extend({},`?

Answer (score 4):

The key difference is `cloneDeep` returns a new object while `extend` mutates the object in place.

```
var a = {x: 1};
_.extend(a, {}) === a // true
_.cloneDeep(a) === a // false
```

In your example:

```
_.extend({}, a) === a // false
_.cloneDeep(a) === a // false
```

what you are extending is not `a`, but the empty object `{}`. So when you strictly compare the result of `_.extend({}, a)` with `a`, you are comparing an extended empty object. When you are comparing `_.cloneDeep(a)` with `a`, you are comparing a clone of `a` with itself. Thus, they may give the same result, but the nature is different.